# Function for finding all the numbers that divide into 50

Tags: python, for-loop, modulo

```
for x in range(-50,50):
    if 50 % x == 0:
        a.append(x)
```

For a homework question, I have to create a function that will find all the numbers between -50 and 50 that divide into 50 (e.g. 1,2,5,10..) However I run into ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero, when I try to run this. If I try it then with x % 50 == 0: it works, but its returning numbers divisible by 50, which isn't what I want.

Any ideas how I could fix this up?

Comment: For homework read [how do I ask a homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Your problem is easily solvable by excluding the `0` special case: `if x and 50 % x == 0:`. the `and` will use a boolean shortcut and it the first operand is falsy (which includes `0`) it will not even consider the second operand.

Answer (score 2):

You can't devide by zero. There multiple ways to fix this problem:

```
for x in range(-50,50):
    if x == 0:
        continue

    if 50 % x == 0:
        a.append(x)
```

or

```
for x in range(-50,50):
    try:
        if 50 % x == 0:
            a.append(x)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For future reference, you may wish to use the [triple backtick code fence syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to help enclose your code block and to ensure the example code be correctly indented such that they would be immediately useful, whether as an answer or any future questions.  I have edited the answer to ensure your intent is preserved, please do feel free to select edit to see the syntax changes or view the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66815142/revisions) to see what was done.

Comment: Don't use a bare `except`. Since you want to catch an error if you divide by zero you should use `except ZeroDivisionError:`.